# How to pass file pointers in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have this situation in a certain class -

```
def f1(self, xxx):
    do stuff with lines from file

def f0(self, filename):
    with open(filename) as fp:
        for lineContent in fp:
            if re.match(lineContent):
                do stuff with next 100+ lines from file
                continue
            else:
                do other stuff while parsing lines
```

The question: What is the best way to use the function f1(...)?

Option 1: Capture lines in an array until there is a sentinel, and then pass this array as the xxx argument for f1().

Option 2: Embed the code contents of f1() into f0(). This also works, but f0() becomes very large and difficult to read.

Looking for: Some way to call f1() with the file pointer, so the method can read/process lines, watch for the sentinel and return control to f0() after it is done.

The perl equivalent code (for what I am looking for) would be:

```
sub f1 { ... }
sub f0 { ...
    while (<$fp>) {
        f1($fp) if /$re2match/;
        continue with other stuff
    }
}
```

Thank you for helping out a novice pythonian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def f1(self, filepointer):
    for _, line in zip(range(100), filepointer):
        # do stuff with the line


def f0(self, filename):
    with open(filename) as infile:
        for lineContent in infile:
            if re.match(lineContent):
                f1(infile)  # only works because of the way file iterators are set up. Otherwise, that for-loop's scoping iterator will bork you here
                # that continue is unnecessary here
            else:
                # do other stuff while parsing lines
```

**UPDATE**: Clarification based on comments

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=zip%20built#zip) is a function that takes multiple iterables (like lists, files, dictionaries, etc) and returns a single iterable of tuples, where the i-th element of each tuple comes from the i-th iterable inputted to `zip`. `zip` also terminates when the smallest of the iterables is exhausted. So, check this out:

```
In [14]: for t in zip('asdf', '1234'): print(t)

('a', '1')
('s', '2')
('d', '3')
('f', '4')

In [15]: for t in zip('asdf', '123'): print(t)
('a', '1')
('s', '2')
('d', '3')
```

Since you asked to process the next 100 lines, `range(100)` seemed to be the ideal tool. `for _, line in ...` is similar to saying `for a, line in ...`, it's just that the underscore is used to denote a variable that we don't want to keep track of (try `print`ing `_` to see what its value is in each iteration of that loop).
If you don't know the exact count of how many lines to process, this is a wrong solution for you.

Comment: Thank you. Follow ups- (1) Could you please explain the zip(range(...)) part, since the exact count of lines to be processed is unknown. What comes out as _? (2) Should the for loop in f0() use infile instead of fp?

Comment: @ManidipSengupta: Updated my answer. Good catch in (2) - I've fixed my code